# Perl-regex not case sensitive when it should be

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to locate some special characters within sentences marked as "\v{G}" or "\v{g}" in a HTML file  to replace them with "Ǧ" and "ǧ", respectively, and save the corrected sentences in a new HTML file.

My regex `(.*)\\v\{(\w)\}(.*)` locate the character to replace but I cannot replace the character based on its case: the resulting file contains:

```
This is a sentence ǧ with a upper case G.
This is a sentence ǧ with a lower case g.
```

instead of:

```
This is a sentence Ǧ with a upper case G.
This is a sentence ǧ with a lower case g.
```

**MWE**

The HTML input file contains:

```
This is a sentence \v{G} with a upper case G.
This is a sentence \v{g} with a lower case g.
```

The perl file contains:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define variables
my ($inputfile, $outputfile, $inputone, $inputtwo, $part1, $specialcharacter, $part2);

# Initialize variables
$inputfile = "TestFile.html";
$outputfile = 'Results.html';

# Open output file
open(my $ofh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "$outputfile");

# Open input file
open(my $ifh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', "$inputfile");

# Read input file
while(<$ifh>) {
    # Analyse _temp.html file to identify special characters
        ($part1, $specialcharacter, $part2) = ($_ =~ /(.*)\\v\{(\w)\}(.*)/);
        if ($specialcharacter == "g") {
            $specialcharacter = "&#487";
        }elsif ($specialcharacter == "G") {
            $specialcharacter = "&#486";# PROBLEM 
        }
        say $ofh "\t\t<p>$part1$specialcharacter$part2";
}

# Close input and output files
close $ifh;
close $ofh;
```

Comment: `if ($specialcharacter eq "g")`. You also have to deal with cases when the pattern doesn't match.

Comment: This solves my problem, you can post it as a response and I will accept it. I also have the code for when the pattern doesn't match but outside of the MWE.

Comment: `$specialcharacter == "g"` would have resulted in a warning (`Argument [...] isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`). You should not have ignored it! (And you should have mentioned it!)

Comment: Yes Raiponce (Rapuntzel) is my favorite princess too.

Comment: @ikegami I would have mentioned the warning if I saw it. I run my .pl file from Windows PowerShell and I never see the information from the compilation are never printed :(

Comment: Not being able to see the output of programs is a major problem with your setup (and not an issue with the use of PowerShell itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `==` is the wrong operator. You should compare the non-numeric scalars using `eq` instead.

An alternative is to create a form of dictionary, a lookup table, and lookup your special characters in that.

```perl
# A map between the special characters and the html code you want in its place.
# Fill it with more if you've got them.
my %SpecialMap = (
    'g' => '&#487;',
    'G' => '&#486;',
);

# Read input file
while(<$ifh>) {
    # loop for as long as \v{character} is found in $_
    while(/\\v\{(\w)\}/) {
        # Look up the character in the dictionary.
        # Fallback if it's not in the map: Use the character as-is instead.
        my $ch = $SpecialMap{$1} || $1;
        # Rebuild $_
        $_ = $` . $ch . $';
    }
    # print the result
    print $ofh $_;
}
```

For the input

```
Both \v{g} and \v{G} in here.
This is a sentence \v{g} with a lower case g.
This is a sentence \v{H} with a upper case H which is not in the map.
This contains nothing special.
```

It'll produce this output:

```
Both &#487; and &#486; in here.
This is a sentence &#487; with a lower case g.
This is a sentence H with a upper case H which is not in the map.
This contains nothing special.
```

Inspired by Polar Bear's comment, you could use `s///ge` to execute a mapping function instead and get the same result:

```perl
my %SpecialMap = (
    'g' => '&#487;',
    'G' => '&#486;',
);

sub mapfunc {
    return $SpecialMap{$1} || $1;
}

# Read input file
while(<$ifh>) {
    # /g substitute all matches on the line
    # /e by executing mapfunc($1) for each
    s/\\v\{(\w)\}/mapfunc($1)/ge;
    print $ofh $_;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer I ever received: not only does it answer my question but it solves the next problem I was planning to tackle :D

Comment: @AlMa Nice! Glad to hear it! Just wait and I'm pretty sure someone will counter this with a one-liner :-)

Comment: Utilization of hashref as `my $SpecialMap = { 'G' => '&#487;', 'g' => '&#486;' };` would allow to avoid unneeded internal loop which could be replaced with `s/\\v\{(G)\}/$SpecialMap->{$1}/gi;`.

Comment: @PolarBear Oh, cool. Would it be possible to make it work for characters without a mapping too?

Comment: @PolarBear I came up with something not exactly the same but it works for characters without mapping.